# Running psql on windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, bash, shell, psql

I need to run a shell script on windows that has psql commands. I installed bash and can run the script but the psql commands are failing. So, I installed the PostgreSQL on the windows machine in this location - `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\scripts\"`. There is a bat file in here named `runpsql.bat` that opens a psql shell. I can connect to my database when I run that bat file but how do I get it to do it from the shell script? Currently, my shell script has commands like -

`psql -d db -U user` etc but those throw a `PSQL: Command not recognized error`

Comment: Find where the `psql.exe` is and add that directory path to the `%PATH%` environment variable. Or call `psql` with its full, absolute path.

Comment: @stickybit I don't have a `psql.exe`. I have a `runpsql.bat`.

Comment: Which starts `psql.exe` according to you. So you have `psql.exe` somewhere.